# VB 2019 Printing the contents of a form in a given format (not print form)

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have several forms that are the result of engineering calculations.  I would like them to print to the printer in a given format, maybe with a letter head etc.  All I can do right now is print the form as it shows on the screen - not what I want.  The VB report viewer seems to depend on database data and I can't find a way to just print the data in my text boxes and tables in a format and position that I want..

Any help will definitely be appreciated..

Comment: How did you print this Form? Can you post that code, plus, possibly, a sample of rendering layout you're looking for? *print to the printer in a given format* is not exactly illuminating.

Comment: You print in WinForms using a `PrintDocument`. Is that what you're doing? If not, it should be, so look it up.

Comment: I can print the form, which is what I am doing now.  I just dont like the format, size etc.  I would like to customize it a little rather than just printing the form that is on the screen..

Comment: You can use the RDLC Report and ReportViewer. You can either pass the data as Report Parameters or create a DataTable on-the-fly, populate it with whatever data is currently on screen and send that datatable to the report

Comment: You've already given the same description in your question. As mentioned, it's not clear why you cannot get the result you want nor it's clear how you want to print this Form. The way you're printing the Form is also undefined. If you post your code, probably someone can suggest the changes needed to achieve a different result. It won't hurt if you also give a less abstract description of what this result should be.

Comment: Maybe this is a better response - I want to create a "report" using the data on the form (textbox1.text etc.) rather than a database as the report viewer is configured to do..